# Can someone explain, in Javascript, when you update Object1, after it is used as the value in Object2 and Object2 receives the same update?

Tags: javascript, object

Reaching out for an explanation of what is happening in this code snippet.

The object variable **`options`** is declared and assigned to an empty object. Then another object variable **`parsedData`** is declared and set with any number of properties, including -> **`options`** that is assigned to empty **`options`** object.

During processing, **`options`** object is updated with new key/value pairs inside of a **`forEach`** loop.

When you output **`parsedData.options`**, it ***IS*** updated and you see references to the new key/value pairs.

I assumed this was javascript variable **`hoisting`**. I googled for a few minutes, but could not confirm.

I thought it was a good question to ask on StackOverFlow. Can someone confirm or provide an explanation?

FYI - The better solution is to update `parsedData.options` NOT options.

#### Code Snippet

```
var options = {}, 
    parsedData = {
        options: options
    }; 

["foo","bar"].forEach(function(name,index) {
    options[name] = index
})

parsedData.options

// options are Updated - Output: Object {foo: 0, bar: 1}
```

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with hoisting (which is about variable scope). It's basic object identity. `options` ***is*** `parsedDate.options`, the exact same object. There are no "two things" that get updated.

Comment: `parsedData.options` is a reference to `options`. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: No, it doesn't reference the variable. Both the property and the variable reference the object.

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, Objects are passed by reference and primitives (String, Number ...) by value.

So when you assign a variable referencing an object to a new one, a reference to this object is passed, and when you update one, the other is updated too, which is normal because they are both pointing to the same object.

So that:

```
let a = 1;
let b = a;
a = 2;
console.log(b); // 1, because b got the value of a
```

and

```
let a = { z: 1 };
let b = a;
a.z = 2;
console.log(b.z) // 2, because b got a reference to the object
```

Comment: "In Javascript, Objects are passed by reference etc" -- this is not the correct terminology, and your examples don't actually explain anything (replace `1` in the first one with `{z:1}` - what changes?)